# Epiphany gives insecure message on valid, secure site

Tags: security, browser, ssl

When I visit this site, https://stream1.fxxy.net/, in Google Chrome or Firefox I am connected and see that it's recognized as a secure site with a valid security certificate verified by COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA. However, visiting the same URL with Epiphany 3.24.1, the connection is blocked with an error message: "This Connection is Not Secure" and "This website’s identification was not issued by a trusted organization." I can then click on an "Accept Risk and Proceed" button to continue.

Firstly, I don't understand why the cert is accepted by Chrome and Firefox but not Epiphany. Any explanation would be appreciated. But more importantly, is there anything I can set/change in Epiphany to have it accept the site as secure and continue on smoothly like the other two browsers?

I'm running the latest Ubuntu Gnome, 17.04 Zesty Zapus.

Comment: I don't know what certificate store Epiphany is using. How would I find the answer? I don't see any setting in its preferences. Knowing this, I could either import certs from Firefox or configure Epiphany to use Firefox's certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question so others don't waste their time with it, and maybe help someone else in the process.

The problem was not with Epiphany but with the certificate. I learned from Michael Catanzaro, a leading Gnome developer, that Firefox and Chrome are fairly permissive in their validation of certificates while Epiphany is intentionally not. The certificate in question was a single certificate without a chain to a recognized signing authority. Firefox and Chrome likely cached the chain from earlier encounters with similar certificates and deemed it acceptable. Epiphany does not cache intermediate chain certificates and rejected the single certificate as insecure.

Hope this helps someone...